# footnotes and widow/orphan control: how to avoid big whitespace on page bottom?

Tags: footnotes, page-breaking, widows-orphans

I'm using `\usepackage[all]{nowidow}` to avoid widows and orphans. However, there is one quite elementary case in which this does not lead to the desired result: As soon as there is a long footnote in the second last line of the paragraph, the footnote will not be broken across pages anymore.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{5.0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0mm}
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=213mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1-2]
\footnote{\lipsum*[1-2]} This is some text finishing this paragraph that reaches to the next line.

\lipsum*[2-7]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the footnote is taken completely to the second page instead of being broken. If I don't include `nowidow.sty`, the footnote is broken across pages but an orphan occurs:

[image]

The desired output would be to have the two final lines of the paragraph on the first page, and the footnote starting on the first but breaking to the second page.

I think this is a very fundamental case and it appears many of times in my document. Is there a way to achieve this behavior automatically?

Comment: Try `\usepackage{bigfoot}`.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to solve the problem!! (At least in MWE cases. I will confirm again after using it on a bigger project.)

Comment: Thanks, it works really well. You might turn that into an answer.

Comment: you might, too ;)

Comment: Alas, I just found out, it does not work poperly, see this new thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391057/bigfoot-footnotes-appear-on-earlier-page

Comment: You write it is a fundamental case. With respect to the reader, why is this big bunch of text in the footnote not worth to be set in the normal text? For me it's rather artificial.