# bigfoot: footnotes appear on earlier page

Tags: footnotes, bigfoot

with the otherwise very useful `bigfoot` package, I'm regularly getting an undesired result: Sometimes, footnotes appear one page too early.

Here is an MWE (simplified/updated 2017-09-13):

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[paperwidth=120mm, paperheight=213mm, %
    left=17mm,right=15mm,top=20mm,bottom=15mm, 
]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\setlength{\parindent}{5.0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0mm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\lipsum*[1]\footnote{Hallo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Removing `\usepackage{bigfoot}` gives the desired result (but I need `bigfoot` for other reasons, see the thread [footnotes and widow/orphan control: how to avoid big whitespace on page bottom?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390491/footnotes-and-widow-orphan-control-how-to-avoid-big-whitespace-on-page-bottom)):

[image]

This is a very fundamental case that I think should not go wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: I see a similar problem with `\documentclass[11pt]{book}`, so it is independent from KOMA-Script.

Comment: Maybe try `\usepackage[para]{manyfoot}` instead of `bigfoot`. I just tried it (using Schweinebacke's modifications), and it did place the footnote on the second page.

Comment: I removed scrbook from the MWE.

Comment: I facing the same problem. Have you managed to solve it?

Comment: `\usepackage{manyfoot}` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

My search brought me to this page but, after a lot of digging, I found out that this was answered elsewhere: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472710 .