# Footnote marks missplaced with bigfoot

Tags: errors, footnotes, bigfoot

With big foot package sometimes footnote text is placed on other page then corresponding footnote mark. [MWE](https://www.overleaf.com/read/qmvcdfrzfcvj):

```
\documentclass[11pt, b5paper, final]{memoir}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{default}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[roman]

\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]\footnote{\blindtext[20]}
\blindtext[5]\footnote{
\blindtext[10]\footnoteB{\blindtext[1]}
\blindtext[30]}
\blindtext[10]\footnote{\blindtext[40]}
\end{document}
```

**Preview**:

[image]
[image]

However if I create similar document without bigfoot it works as expected. [MWE](https://www.overleaf.com/read/pyhfncjpkjgw)

```
\documentclass[11pt, b5paper, final]{memoir}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]\footnote{\blindtext[20]}
\blindtext[5]\footnote{
\blindtext[10]
\blindtext[30]}
\blindtext[10]\footnote{\blindtext[40]}
\end{document}
```

**Preview**:

[image]
[image]

**Question** how can I fix bigfoot that marks appear on same page as text? I can choose other package for footnotes, but i need insert second level footnotes into first level footnote (as in bigfoot MWE).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simpler example for the problem is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
abc
\footnote{abc\kant[1-8]}

\newpage
abc
\footnote{blub}

\end{document}
```

`bigfoot` has obviously a problem with long footnotes followed by more footnotes.

The problem appears the first time in texlive 2015, and this indicates the source of the problem: at that time latex change the allocation system for extended registers and `bigfoot` adjusted to this change by not loading etex anymore. But bigfoot tests in one place `\count266` which with etex contained the marks allocation, while in the new system `\count256` should be used.

Correcting this number solves the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\FN@allmarks{266}{256}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
abc
\footnote{abc\kant[1-8]}

\newpage
abc
\footnote{blub}

\end{document}
```

Inform the maintainer so that he adjusts bigfoot.

Comment: Already wrote a letter to maintainer with this bug. And will send a follow up with your fix. Thanks.