# Unwanted vertical space with `\FN@beforebreak` in `bigfoot`

Tags: footnotes, bigfoot

I use `bigfoot` for creating two types of footnotes. And also I want to place dots when long footnote continues on next page (`\FN@beforebreak`). I use `\raisebox{12pt}[0pt][0pt]` and it should be 0 height. But there still appears vertical space after the footnote break.

MWE ([overleaf](https://ru.overleaf.com/read/szpcpfncptky)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote{default}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[alph]

\setlength{\skip\footinsB}{0pt}

% fix bug in bigfoot 2015/08/30 2.1
% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471379/footnote-marks-missplaced-with-bigfoot/
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\FN@allmarks{266}{256}{}{\fail}

\renewcommand\FN@beforebreak{\hbox{%
\raisebox{12pt}[0pt][0pt]{\hspace\textwidth~\dots{}}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Blindtext[1][1]
\blindtext[1]\footnote{\Blindtext[3][2] New line}
Some words\footnoteB{See the vertical space}
\Blindtext[2][1]
Text\footnoteB{no vertical space}

\end{document}
```

Preview before break:

[image]

Preview without break:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the beforebreak marker is typeset on the line below the text. Yes, you reach up by a line using `\raisebox` but that extra line is still there. Here are two versions that vertically backspace to hide that blank line.

First, backing up after the dots

```
\renewcommand\FN@beforebreak{\hbox{%
  \raisebox{12pt}[0pt][0pt]{\hspace\textwidth~\dots{}}%
}\vspace*{-12pt}}
```

Or backing up before the dots, and not raising them

```
\renewcommand\FN@beforebreak{\vskip-12pt
  \rlap{\hspace\textwidth~\dots}%
}
```

Probably most satisfying is to avoid the interline skip entirely rather than erasing it

```
\renewcommand\FN@beforebreak{\begingroup\nobreak
  \baselineskip\z@skip \lineskiplimit-\maxdimen
  \rlap{\hspace\textwidth~\dots}%
\endgroup}
```

In the first two definitions I assumed line-spacing of 12pt, as in the question. A virtue of the third alternative is that no such assumption is needed.